# Stdin not flushed after normal dummy program

Tags: c, stdin, flush

Here is a piece of c code that I wrote after testing some stuffs.

I know this is not a vulnerability concern, but I don't understand why the stdin is not flushed after the normal return of the program, at the point that the prompt get back stdin,stdout,stderr. I mean why the remaining chars on stdin are redirected to stdout after the end of the normal execution of the program and not flushed?

```
$cat dummy.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){

    char rbuf[100];

        if (read(0, rbuf,5) == -1){
        perror("learn to count");
        printf("errno = %d.\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
        //printf("rbuf : %s\n",rbuf);
    return 1;   
}
```

Here the execution:

```
$ gcc -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy 
AAAAA /bin/sh
$  /bin/sh
sh-3.2$ exit
exit
$
```

I guess this is just the remaining string of the stdin printed on the mew stdout which is the prompt. Plus the line feed at the end, it somehow emulates the enter pressed by the user to execute a command. What's going on? I'm just curious to know more about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your guess is right, these are extra characters in `stdin`:

do this:

```
void flush_stdin()
{
   while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Note: do not use `fflush()` on `stdin` because that is undefined behavior

**edit**

The `stdin` is wired to the terminal which starts the program(which is `bash`). This starts a new program `dummy` and the `stdin` of `dummy` is wired to the `stdin` of `bash`.

From there on, the `dummy` process `read`s five characters, neglects the others(leaving them in the `stdin` buffer). When the control returns to `bash` it waits until there is atleast one character to read from in the `buffer`. Low and behold, there are characters in the `stdin` buffer, hence the program - instead of waiting, starts to read from the `stdin` and since the `stdin` at the end, contains `\n` the process is actually executed. This starts `/bin/sh`. The rest is up to `/bin/sh` to worry about!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I know that I can flush manually. My question was not "Can I flush it manually and how" but "Why is it not done by the OS or whatever after a normal return of my program". Because the redirection of stdin, stdout and stderr should be done when the prompt get back the hand, but still stdin is not automatically flushed.

So I'm still curious to know more about that :)

Comment: Because the OS expects that the data in the input buffer directed to the executable be consumed by the executable. The input buffer is just a queue of data waiting to be consumed. There is no information as to which executable can and cannot consume this data. So the OS cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

To execute your program, the shell calls fork(2) to create a child process, and in the child process calls exec(3) to replace itself with the "dummy" program.

I imagine there is something like this in the shell's source code (if it is written in C):

```
if (fork() == 0)
    execlp(program, arguments)
```

The child process inherits the file descriptors of the parent; in this case the shell. So the child process has the same stdin/stdout as the shell that exec'd it, which is the virtual terminal.

I'm not sure exactly how, but I'd imagine the parent process (the original shell you typed the command in) disregards stdin somehow whilst the child process is running.

When the program exits, the shell gets its stdin back. Any extra characters that weren't read by the your program will go to the shell. And then of course the shell just treats them as a command.

If you try using fgetc(3) instead of read(2) at first it appears the extra characters are lost, not sent to the shell... *but*, if you unbuffer stdin, you get the same effect using fgetc(2), ie: extra characters go back to the shell.

```
char rbuf[100];
setbuf(stdin, NULL); // with this line - same effect as using read(2)
                     // without it - extra characters are lost
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    rbuf[i] = (char)fgetc(stdin);
```

By default stdin is line buffered. So it looks like this behaviour is avoided when using buffered stdin because the entire line is read, and extra characters are discarded, whereas unbuffered stdin (or low level reads) will not read until the end of the line, and extra characters remain to be read by the parent (shell) once your program exits.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the above answer had already basically said the same thing in an edit.